# Getting the linux error code from make in Vim

Tags: linux, vim, error-code

I'm trying to get the "0 of success, nonzero if error" return code from make in Vim. Specifically, I am on Ubuntu and using `v:shell_error` does not work.

After digging around and looking at [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679475/vim-script-to-compile-tex-source-and-launch-pdf-only-if-no-errors) it seems to be because of my shellpipe setting, which is

`shellpipe=2>&1| tee`

The `tee` pipes the make output back into vim. The shell is apparently returning the error code from tee to vim and not from make. How do I get make's error code instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to make a custom function for that. E.g. using `:call system("make > make.out")` run make redirecting output into a file. After that load the error file using `:cf make.out`. Never tried that myself, though.

In the end, results of `make` might be also simply checked by testing whether the result is there, in the file system:

```
:make | if !filereadable("whatever-make-was-supposed-to-create") | throw "Make failed!!!" | endif
```

(Here the '|' symbol is vim's command separator.) Assigning that to a keyboard shortcut would remove the need for typing.

P.S. I usually try to make my programs to produce no warnings, so I never really came across the issue. What BTW leads to another possible solution: simply remove warnings (or simply undesired output lines) using e.g. `grep -v tabooword` from the make output by overriding the `'makeprg'`. What is actually described in the help: `:h 'makeprg'`.

P.P.S. *I got started on the VIM...* Provided that you also use bash as a shell. Did you tried to add to the exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} to the shellpipe? E.g.:

```
:set shellpipe=2>&1\ \|\ tee\ %s;exit\ \${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Just tested that on Debian and it worked for me. `:h 'shellpipe'` for more.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can currently think of is creating two wrapper scripts for make and tee. I'm sure there's an easier way, but for now you might try this:

Create a make wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

make $@
echo $? > ~/exit_code_cache
```

Create a tee wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tee $@
return `cat ~/exit_code_cache` # (or do something else with the exit code)
```

Use the new make `:set makeprg=mymake` and setup your own `shellpipe` that uses your tee wrapper (`shellpipe=2>&1 | mytee`).

It's not tested, but the idea should be clear. Hope it helps.